# Unity Take damage while colliding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey i am making a zombie game and i want everytime the zombie colides with my player it should deal damage every 2 seconds as long as they are colliding it should continue. while not colliding it should stop. what i did is this code bellow and the problem with it is that when i collide with the zombie it does damage once and stops i need to collide with it again for it to deal damage can anyone help so the zombie deals damage as long as they are colliding and the damage should be dealt every 2 seconds, thanks for the help :)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{

    
    public float Health = 100f;
    public bool gameOver;
    private Animator playerAnim;
    float timeColliding;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        playerAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            playerAnim.SetBool("PlayerDeath", true);
            gameOver = true;
        }

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            
            Debug.Log("Enemy started colliding with player.");


            this.Health -= 10;

        }
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not good at unity, but i think something like this will work. Place all code inside while loop in my code to function in your code called to detect collision. And place **isEven** outside that function. You can test my code in c# compiler. For example if you replace **//reduce health here** with **Console.WriteLine("reduced");** this code will print reduced every 2 second

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool isEven = false;
        while(true){
            var timeSpan = DateTime.Now;
            if(timeSpan.Second %2 == 0){
                if(isEven == false){
                    //reduce health here
                }
                isEven = true;
            }
            else{
                isEven = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your code it will look like this:

```
public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool isEven = false;
    public float Health = 100f;
    public bool gameOver;
    private Animator playerAnim;
    float timeColliding;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        playerAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            playerAnim.SetBool("PlayerDeath", true);
            gameOver = true;
        }

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            
            Debug.Log("Enemy started colliding with player.");
            var timeSpan = DateTime.Now;
            if(timeSpan.Second %2 == 0){
                if(isEven == false){
                    //reduce health here
                    this.Health -= 10;
                }
                isEven = true;
            }
            else{
                isEven = false;
            }


        }
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but unfortunately everytime i use while loops in unity it crashes idk why but it just doesnt work. thanks anyway :)

Comment: No dude.. you cant use infinity loop in unity. you know Update() function is called every frame right? Its already in a while true loop so you cant add while true loop inside another while true. What you need to do is take every code inside my while loop and paste it to your OnCollisionEnter().

Comment: I edit my answer dude.. i show you how to implement my code to your code. You can just copy paste it now

Comment: ohh ok il try it

Comment: DateTime.Now what should i declare it as?

Comment: Its a build in c# Property.. you don't need to declare it, just import it from System namespace(using System;).. Read this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-5.0

Comment: i tried the code but it still isnt working

Comment: What's wrong? can you explain?

Comment: soo everytime i hit the Enemy it takes damage but i want it to take damage while the enemy is colliding with my player

Comment: So you mean damage only occurs one time?

Comment: yes its happening once everytime i collide with enemy, i want to keep damagin me if i am still colliding. btw thanks for ur help sorry if i am being too much i really appreciate this

Comment: Oh.. OnCollisionEnter trigger only once when collision happen not every update. You need to replace it with function that detects collision while it happens. I cant find it on internet. Maybe you can just move my code inside OnCollisionEnter to update function. Create a new variable and inside OnCollisionEnter you assign that variable to a new value. check it in update function and when value of new variable is right, run my code. And you need a way to detect collision leave(I don't know how) and inside collision leave, update your new variable so update function don't reduce Health variable.

Comment: Oh.. i found it. Its OnCollisionStay(). So what you need to do is replace OnCollisionEnter with OnCollisionStay: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1455661/use-of-oncollisionstay.html

Comment: i tried doing both OnCollisionStay and calling collision in update they are just not working  :(

Comment: it wont even detect that they are colliding because it wont put anything in log

Comment: nvm ur code worked i just added a box collider to my player too and now its working thank youu

Comment: You're welcome.. if you want to change how many second health will drain, just change 2 in this line to any number you need `if(timeSpan.Second % 2 == 0)`